# Where is gatling.conf file?

Tags: gatling

I cannot find a gatling.conf file anywhere on my PC(kubuntu 14.04).
Gatling 2.1.4 was installed via sbt.

Should I create it by myself?

Is there any chance to tune-up Gatling for data transferring  to Graphite via code of test?

Comment: By 'installed via sbt', do you mean that you're using Gatling's SBT plugin ?

Comment: Pierre, looks like I put it in a wrong way. Gatling wasn't installed via sbt, sbt just takes it from repository for project building.

I have an idea to put gatling.conf with the content like in tutorial (http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/graphite/index.html#configuration-of-gatling ) into src/test/resources folder. Could it help me? 

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can copy the `gatling.conf` files from Gatling's bundles (downloadable on http://gatling.io). However, if you're going to use SBT, I highly suggest that you use Gatling's SBT Plugin, which takes care of running your simulations, and also offer a `copyConfigFiles` which will take care of copying the configuration files for you.

Comment: Pierre, thanks you a lot! Task `copyConfigFiles` helped me.